# RegSetValueEx doesn't create a String Value

Tags: c++, regedit

I read some documentation and looked at code examples but I can't find any reasons for my code not to work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

void AddSubKeyWithValue(HKEY hRootKey, LPWSTR strSubKey, LPCTSTR StringVal, LPCTSTR data)
{
    HKEY hKey;
    RegOpenKeyEx(hRootKey, strSubKey, NULL, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);
    RegSetValueEx(hRootKey, StringVal, NULL, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)&data, sizeof(REG_SZ));
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
    return;
}


void main() {

    AddSubKeyWithValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",L"Slayer Tool", L"c:\\Slayer\\Update.exe");

    system("pause");
    return;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RegSetValueEx call is all off. The first parameter should be a subkey handle, not HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. The 5th parameter should point to the data, not to the pointer to data. The 6th parameter should contain the string length, in bytes (keep in mind it's a wide string), including the terminating null.

So reformulate like this:

```
RegSetValueEx(hKey, StringVal, NULL, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)data, sizeof(wchar_t)*(wcslen(data)+1));
```

Most importantly, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE is read-only for non-admin users, and even for admin users it's read-only without privilege elevation.

Also, `system("pause")` is an awful way to wait for a key press. Call "getch()" instead.

Comment: it didn't work but you are right in my parameters errors.

Comment: Always check return values!  `RegSetValueEx()` (or more likely `RegOpenKeyEx()`) is failing with an error that you are not catching.  Don't use `KEY_ALL_ACCESS`, in this case `KEY_SET_VALUE` by itself would suffice, provided the code is running with admin rights since it is trying to write to `HKLM`, which is protected from writes by non-admins. when accessing a securable resource, NEVER ask for more permissions than you ACTUALLY need.